# TLocationSensor is not working on Windows 10

Tags: delphi, geolocation, delphi-10-seattle

I wrote simple application with TLocationService, but it seems that when my app is running on windows 10, it can't get access to location sensor (it worked on another tablet with windows 8). I activate LocationService, but there is no any state or location change events. GPS is working correctly, internal maps app shows current position. I have found some mentions in the web that Location API is not working in Windows 10 and it was replaced with Windows.​Devices.​Geolocation. Is it really so?

Comment: I have an app where the location sensor works OK on Windows 10

Comment: Did you allow your app access to location in Settings - Location?

Comment: I'll bite - where is Settings - Location? This is the app that I speak of: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/OpenWeatherDemo

Comment: @DaveNottage [UNRELATED] Take a look at my solution, using the very same API, but supporting even more weather services... http://weather.jdsoftwareinc.com/ For the record, I too use the `TLocationSensor` for this project, and also have no issues with location services on Windows 10. Of course, I also have all the updates installed.

Comment: @JerryDodge Thanks for the link! I did the OpenWeatherDemo just as an exercise for a blog article on how easy it is to make cross-platform apps with Delphi ;-)

Comment: @Dave Nottage Your demo app is not working too. After start it shows weather for Hindmarsh, but didn't get my location. I added ShowMessage in LocationSensorLocationChanged and it doesn't appear.

Comment: @DaveNottage Settings - Location https://alssl.askleomedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/win10_location_settings2-600x430.png

Comment: @ventik That screenshot does not show all the settings, however at the top of the settings on my system, it says Location for this device is on. General location is off, but the app still works for me